# Create mutually exclusive, not overlapping regexes

Tags: php, regex, laravel, template-engine, laravel-4

A template engine processes both `{{foo}}` and `{{{bar}}}`, they correspond to different treatments.

Currently, the source is processed with `preg_replace`'s like so: `{{\s*(.+?)\s*}}` and `{{{\s*(.+?)\s*}}}`.

The problem is, these regexes overlap, e.g. `{{\s*(.+?)\s*}}` matches in `{{{bar}}}`.

*Important note:* the markers `{{`, `{{{`, `}}`, `}}}` are user-configurable in the real code. So usual solutions like `[^{}]` cannot be used.

The current solution is to replace `{{{ }}}`'s before `{{ }}`'s, but that's not robust enough. Indeed, the markers being user-configurable, the user can easily set the markers to values which break the app.

I'm trying to make robuster regexes which are mutually exclusive, not order-dependant. I've already tried using assertions, conditionals, etc. without success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

By the way, use of regex is not mandatory, as long as the code doesn't become overlong.

Comment: Just retagged to increase visibility in "laravel", if you wanted the template-engine tag maybe swap it for blade.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need to try some lookarounds. Here is my sample which shows the two different matches tests

```
$Matches = @()
$String = 'A template{{{bar}}} engine processes both {{foo}} and {{{bar}}}, they correspond to different treatments.'
write-host "Foo matches"
([regex]'(?<!{){{([^{}]*)}}(?!})').matches($String) | foreach {
    write-host "at $($_.Groups[1].Index) = '$($_.Groups[1].Value)'"
    } # next match

Write-Host 
write-host "Bar matches"
$Matches = @()
([regex]'{{{([^{}]*)}}}').matches($String) | foreach {
    write-host "at $($_.Groups[1].Index) = '$($_.Groups[1].Value)'"
    } # next match
```

yields

```
Foo matches
at 44 = 'foo'

Bar matches
at 13 = 'bar'
at 57 = 'bar'
```

I've modified your inner text test to look for any non "} or "{" characters this way all characters inside are returned.

Comment: Sorry I meant to add that this was written in powershell.

Comment: I've edited my post to emphasize this point: The markers `{{`, `{{{`, `}}`, `}}}` are user-configurable in the real code. So usual solutions like `[^{}]` cannot be used. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: If the markers are user-configurable in the real code, then you already know what those values are and can substitute them into the regex.

Comment: If these markers are user configurable [aka random]  unless there is a known delimiter surrounding the open and/or close markers it's unlikely you can create a regex to capture all edge cases. For example if a user Bar selected "123" and "321" as their set of tags and user Foo selected "12" and "21" then unless you know to limit  for the "3"s when searching for Foo's tags then you'll also find 3bar3.